# Javascript Focus Is Not Working on Aspx Page

Tags: javascript

Hy Guys,

Please Look at the code and Try to Help Out. The function ive written is not working but its RUNNING properly. Its about To set focus on next content on page im using it on an ASPX page. Heres my code Below :

```
function SetFocusOnSave(CTag,NTag)
{
    alert('Running'+CTag+NTag);

    var CurrentTag=document.getElementById(CTag);    
    var NextTag = document.getElementById(NTag);

    if ( (event.keyCode==13)||(event.keyCode==9) )    
    {    
        if(CurrentTag.value=="")    
        {    
            alert("Please Enter Detail First");    
            CurrentTag.focus();    
        }

        if(CurrentTag.value!="")
        {
            event.returnValue=true;    
            document.getElementById(NextTag).focus();
        }    
    }
}

snametxt.Attributes.Add("onkeypress",    
              SetFocusOnSave('<%=snametxt.ClientID%>','<%=sdesctxt.ClientID%>');");
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to replace

```
document.getElementById(NextTag).focus();
```

with

```
NextTag.focus();
```

?

Comment: have you tried to supprime the instruction "event.returnValue=true;" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `return false;` after you found the false in validation otherwise the flow will continue till end.

Try this function:

```
function SetFocusOnSave(CTag, NTag) {

    alert('Running' + CTag + NTag);   
    var CurrentTag = document.getElementById(CTag);    
    var NextTag = document.getElementById(NTag);

    if ((event.keyCode == 13) || (event.keyCode == 9))    
    {

        if (CurrentTag.value == "")    
        {

            alert("Please Enter Detail First");    
            CurrentTag.focus();
            return false;
        } 

        if (CurrentTag.value != "") {
            event.returnValue = true;    
            NextTag.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: I've Tried But Not Working :( !!

Comment: It works for me, please see - http://jsfiddle.net/W9vsu/1/. 

I have passed "if" condition, since I couldn't execute the keycode with 13/9.

Comment: For onKeyPress, you should have to bind the above function while loading the page. So that, JS will capture key-events and execute them  when an event happens (here 13 or 9).

Comment: have you tried to supprime the instruction "event.returnValue=true;"?

Answer (score 0):

Hy Guys Ive Tried A NEW CODE AND Fortunately Its Working Fine Here its my Code

```js
function Navigation(CTag, NTag, Number) {

    var CurrentTag = document.getElementById(CTag);
    var NextTag = document.getElementById(NTag);
    var IsNumber = Number; //Checking if value is number

    if (NextTag.disabled == true) {
        NextTag.disabled = false;
        NextTag.className = "txt";
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        CurrentTag.focus();
        event.returnvalue = false;
    }

    if (event.keyCode != 9) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            if (IsNumber == "Y") {

                if (NextTag.disabled == true) {
                    NextTag.disabled = false;
                }
                if (CurrentTag.value != "") {
                    NextTag.focus();
                    event.returnvalue = true;
                }
                if (CurrentTag.value == "") {
                    alert('Please Enter Value To Proceed Further.');
                    CurrentTag.focus();
                    event.returnvalue = false;
                }
                if (isNaN(CurrentTag.value)) {
                    alert("Please Enter A Valid Number");
                    CurrentTag.value = "";
                    CurrentTag.focus();
                }
            }
            if (IsNumber == "N") {
                if (CurrentTag.value == "") {
                    alert('Please Enter Value To Proceed Further.');
                    CurrentTag.focus();
                    event.returnvalue = false;
                }
                if (CurrentTag.value != "") {
                    NextTag.focus();
                    event.returnvalue = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks ya'll !! :)